# SessionScoped bean created several times

Tags: tomcat, jakarta-ee, primefaces, jsf-2.2

I work with Eclipse Mars.2, the system has Java 1.8 update 102 for 64bits but this project uses Java 1.7, JSF Mojarra 2.2, Primefaces 6.0 and Tomcat 7.0.53/7.0.54/8.0.1/8.0.11.
I have created the smallest test project in order to show the problem.

The test project consist of 2 pages created with templates, with a menubar on top to browse and a selectOneMenu also on top to select the current language.
The current language is stored in a variable in a session bean which is used in both pages and is refreshed every time we change the selectOneMenu.
When I run the APP on Tomcat 7.0.53 / Tomcat 8.0.1 or lesser versions it works percfectly, the SessionScoped bean is created just once and the value is kept correctly stored.
The problem happens when I run the same APP in Tomcat 7.0.54 / Tomcat 8.0.11 or later versions, in such case the SessionScoped bean is created everytime it is used, and as the current language value is initialized it is always set to the default ( english ).

I have researched a lot and asked in several sites but without any luck.
Maybe someone can iluminate me?
Thanks a lot in advance!!

As I use templates a page is always composed of head_view.xhtml + index_view.xhtml / page2_view.xhtml + foot_view.xhtml (index_view.xhtml=page2_view.xhtml and the foot part is empty)

**head_view.xhtml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
  xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
  xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
  xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">

  <f:view locale="#{sesion.currentLanguage}">   
    <h:head></h:head>
    <h:body>
        <h:form>
            <p:selectOneMenu id="selectlanguage" value="#{sesion.selectedLanguage}" converter="languageConverter" var="t" >
                  <f:selectItems value="#{sesion.languages}" var="idi" itemLabel="#{idi.name}" itemValue="#{idi}" />

                  <p:column>
                      <h:outputText value="#{t.name}" />
                  </p:column>  

                  <p:ajax event="change" listener="#{sesion.changeLanguage}" />
             </p:selectOneMenu>

             <p:menubar>

                 <p:menuitem value="#{msg.btn1}" action="#{headBB.goTo('index')}" />

                 <p:menuitem value="#{msg.btn2}" action="#{headBB.goTo('page2')}" />

             </p:menubar>                                                                                               
        </h:form>
    </h:body>
  </f:view>
</html>
```

**index_view.xhtml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
  xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
  xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
  xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
  xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">

  <f:view locale="#{sesion.currentLanguage}">
    <h:head></h:head>
    <h:body>
        <h:form> 
        INDEX<br/>           
        #{msg.random_text}
        </h:form>
    </h:body>
  </f:view> 
</html>
```

**headBB.java**

```
package beans;

import java.io.Serializable;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.RequestScoped;
import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;

@ManagedBean
@RequestScoped
public class HeadBB implements Serializable {


    private static final long serialVersionUID = 7510243725613503561L;

    public HeadBB() {

    }

    public String goTo(String pageName){

        String url;

        switch (pageName) {
        case "index":
            getsesion().setCurrentPage("index");
            url = "index?faces-redirect=true";
            break;
        case "page2":
            getsesion().setCurrentPage("rent");
            url = "page2?faces-redirect=true";
            break;
        default:
            getsesion().setCurrentPage("index");
            url = "index?faces-redirect=true";
            break;
        }

        return url;
    }

    public static Sesion getsesion() { 
        FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance(); 
        return (Sesion) context.getApplication().evaluateExpressionGet(context, "#{sesion}", Sesion.class);       
    }    

}
```

**Language.java**

```
package beans;

import java.io.Serializable;

public class Language implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 8302229459482632486L;

    private String code;
    private String name;

    public Language(String code, String name) {
        this.code = code;
        this.name = name;
    }
    //getter and setters
}
```

**sesion.java**

```
package beans;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Locale;
import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import javax.faces.application.NavigationHandler;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.SessionScoped;
import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;


@ManagedBean
@SessionScoped
public class Sesion implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 5845708623625499704L;

    private String currentPage = "";
    private Locale currentLanguage;
    private Language selectedLanguage;
    private List<Language> languages;

    public Sesion() {

    }

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        currentPage = "index";
        currentLanguage = new Locale("en", "GB");
        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getViewRoot().setLocale(currentLanguage);

        languages = new ArrayList<Language>();
        languages.add(new Language("ES", "Espanol"));
        languages.add(new Language("EN", "English"));

        selectedLanguage = new Language("EN", "English");
    }

    public void changeLanguage() {
        Locale tempLocale = new Locale("en", "GB");
        switch (selectedLanguage.getCode()) {
        case "ES":
            tempLocale = new Locale("es", "ES");
            break;
        default:
            tempLocale = new Locale("en", "GB");
            break;
        }
        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getViewRoot().setLocale(tempLocale);
        this.setCurrentLanguage(tempLocale);

        // we refresh ALL browsing to the current page
        FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
        NavigationHandler navigationHandler = context.getApplication().getNavigationHandler();
        navigationHandler.handleNavigation(context, null, this.currentPage + "?faces-redirect=true");
    }
    //getter and setters    
}
```

Thanks a lot for your time!

Comment: did you check if the sessionId stays the same? If it does not, it is not JSF related but a different purely tomcat problem

Comment: How can I check whether the session ID stays the same in Tomcat?

Comment: I have tried to specify the sessionscoped bean name with "@ManagedBean(name = "sesion")" just to be sure that it uses the name I'm using with the function that recovers the session bean but it doesn't work...

Comment: I have also tried to change the way I recover the sessionscoped bean just in case with: @ManagedProperty(value="#{sesion}") private Sesion sesion;  and with FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance(); 
     return (Sesion)context.getExternalContext().getSessionMap().get("sesion"); Any of them worked...

Comment: The creation of the sessionscoped bean is triggered in every place where it is being referenced, in XHTML (the head_view.xhtml selectOneMenu) or in java (the headBB.java). It seems that the sessionscoped bean is being lost and I don't understand why... The most amazing is the fact tha it only happens in one Tomcat version and not in other...

Comment: session id is a cookie (or appended to the url)